# I return a defined type on the client side in WCF. that is, a generic T

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, service, serviceknowntype

how can I return a defined type on the client side in WCF. that is, a generic T. to use a generic service.

I have this error: Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types.

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
List<T> getResultOperation<T>(bool tran = false);
```

my service:

```
public List<T> getResultOperation<T>(bool tran = false)
        {
            List<T> lista = new List<T>();

            return lista;
        }
```

my client:

```
ServiceReference instance = new Servicereference();
List<myClass> list = List<myClass>();
list = instance.getResultOperation<myClass>();
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with that code ?

Comment: this error. Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types.

Comment: Not so sure if what you want is possible. Jeff W. Barnes wrote in 2007 "WCF does not support the use of generic methods for service operation. In other words, only concrete types can be used for service operations. Open generic types cannot be used. Now, it is important to clarify this is not a limitation of WCF. Rather, it is a limitation of WSDL, which is used to expose service metadata to consumers. There is no construct within WSDL to define a generic type".